# Strange errors: can't mount one partition

Tags: mount, sd-card

I have on a SD card 2 partitions (got from NIXOS Aarch64 image), and sometimes I get a very annoying issue on the partition 2: basically, once I mount it, and unmount it, I can't remount it anymore except if I reboot. I get an error:

```
[me@me:~]$ sudo LANG=C mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /tmp/mmc
mount: /tmp/mmc: mount(2) system call failed: File exists.
```

I tried to check the `mount`, `fsck` and `lsof` commands, but don't see any reason why the partition cannot be mounted. Here is for example a transcript of what I tried:

```
[me@me:~]$ lsblk
NAME                       MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
[...]
mmcblk0                    179:32   0  29,7G  0 disk  
├─mmcblk0p1                179:33   0    30M  0 part  
└─mmcblk0p2                179:34   0  29,7G  0 part  
nvme0n1                    259:0    0 953,9G  0 disk  
[...]

[me@me:~]$ mount | grep mmcblk0

[me@me:~]$ mount | grep /tmp/

[me@me:~]$ mkdir /tmp/mmc

[me@me:~]$ sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /tmp/mmc
mount: /tmp/mmc: mount(2) system call failed: File exists.

[me@me:~]$ sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /tmp/mmc

[me@me:~]$ sudo lsof | grep mmcblk0p2

[me@me:~]$ sudo fsck /dev/mmcblk0p2 
fsck de util-linux 2.33.2
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
NIXOS_SD : récupération du journal
Définition du compteur d'i-noeuds libres à 1786283 (était 1786345)
Définition du compteur des blocs libres à 6611933 (était 6616142)
NIXOS_SD : propre, 155797/1942080 fichiers, 1170083/7782016 blocs

[me@me:~]$ sudo fsck /dev/mmcblk0p2 
fsck from util-linux 2.33.2
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
NIXOS_SD: clean, 155797/1942080 files, 1170083/7782016 blocks

[me@me:~]$ sudo mkdir /tmp/mmc2

[me@me:~]$ sudo LANG=C mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /tmp/mmc
mount: /tmp/mmc: mount(2) system call failed: File exists.

[me@me:~]$ LANG=C umount /dev/mmcblk0p2
umount: /dev/mmcblk0p2: not mounted.
```

-- EDIT --
Dmesg gives me the following errors. I also have few pages of debug informations, with Call Trace, Code, registers... The errors I see are:

```
[76667.022409] sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename '/fs/ext4/mmcblk0p2'
[...]
[76667.022608] kobject_add_internal failed for mmcblk0p2 with -EEXIST, don't try to register things with the same name in the same directory.
[76667.022667] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mount failed
```

Comment: check `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog` Also check your kernel ring buffer via `dmesg` command.

Comment: What sort of filesystem is there ? (can we assume that running e2fsck + journaling info, its an ext4 ?)

Comment: @PersianGulf You can find the errors I get in my edit, thanks for the help

Comment: @MC68020 yes, it's ext4

Comment: For what is the reason why it works the first time after reboot : /tmp is usually cleared at boot time. Then with your first fsck, recovering journal tells that your fs has not been unmounted properly. Could you please 1/ mount it after boot 2/ ls -ails /mnt 3/ unmount it 4/ fsck 5/ ls -ails /mnt

Comment: And additionally pleas ls -ails /sys/fs/ext4 before first mount and after unmount

Comment: @MC68020: I mount in /tmp and I ls the /mnt folder, or did you mean that I should ls the folder containing my mount, like /tmp?

Comment: I mean (tmp supposed to be cleaned at boot time) On console as root (no sudo) 1/ cd /tmp 2/ mkdir mmc 3/ ls -ails /sys/fs/ext4 4/ mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /tmp/mmc 5/ ls -ails /sys/fs/ext4 6/ df -a (will replace avantageusement ;-) ) the ls you worried about 7/ umount and repeat 3/4/5/6. 8/ redo 4/ and whatever the result replay 5/6/. Then if it works (remount successful) reboot and replay 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8 with your sudo.

Comment: Ok thanks @MC68020, I don't have access right now to the SD card, but I'll try next week when I get it back!